# Verifying User from MySQL database in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am making a School management system. In this system, first we have to create  a user which gets stored in MySQL Database of Usernames and Passwords. But I am stuck at that step where we have to verify the user. How can I do that? I just need a rough idea guys..:)

Comment: You could do a search for that user and get the Count of how many rows are returned if the users are unique.

Comment: Don't forget to hash the user's password before storing it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "verify the user" but if you mean by checking if the user is actually in the database, use SQL syntax similar to this:

```
select username from usertable where username = 'username';
```

If you have a row returned, then you know that the user is in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Verifying could imply several things among : 
- checking if the user exists 
- checking if the combination username/password is valid for authentication 
- checking if the user profile is valid to interact in your application

This list is most probably not complete

Comment: I just want to authenticate the user and proceed into the system.

Comment: @Ankur : Well use the authentication subroutine with the new username and password. If it is successful, then verification is complete. Otherwise, you should maybe destroy the user and redo the creation ....